# WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist Build info: version: 'unknown' with ChromeDriver Selenium on Linux Server

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run my suite in oracle linux server release 7.6 run
there is also chrome 76 is installed in the server when i try to run both with chrome and headless chrom,everytime its giving the follwing error.

Even i tried from chrome 246 driver to chrome 79 driver on hit and trial basis,but no luck

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'arusprint02', ip: '100.104.104.102', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.35-1902.3.1.el7uek.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x55c9ab4f1129 <unknown>
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at utils.Intelligence_Browser.SetconfigurationBrowser(Intelligence_Browser.java:142)
    at utils.RunnerArf.main(RunnerArf.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
..
```

Code i am using here:

```
} else if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.out.println("Chrome is Starting");
            String chromedriverPath = PropertyfileConfig.getStringValueFromProperty("chromedriverpath");

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("test-type");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>");
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            System.out.println("Chrome driver selected");
            driver.get(Url);

        } else if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("headless")) {

            String chromedriverPath = PropertyfileConfig.getStringValueFromProperty("chromedriverpath");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
            options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--headless");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.get(Url);
```

Comment: which code snippet are you currently running - with or without headless? Are you facing issues in both.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'arusprint02', ip: '100.104.104.102', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.35-1902.3.1.el7uek.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with the **Selenium** language binding.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *chromedriver* version is not clear from the error trace logs.
- Your *chrome= 75.0* version is not clear from the error trace logs.
- Your *Selenium Client* **version** is not recognized.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client* , *ChromeDriver* and the *Chrome Browser*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Comment: Browser Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) , and i tried with chromedriver linux version 246 to chromedriver 79 version, but everytime same error,

Comment: @user2626417 Please follow the canonical steps and instructions provided with in the answer and let me know the status.

Comment: one more thing want to specify i am running with prject jar file like java -suit.jar